# Does the phone need to be connected to the internet so that the network provider can determine a location? 

Tags: android, networking, geolocation

Does the phone need to be connected to the internet all the time, so that the network provider can determine a location?

When I test my app on my phone, and in `Settings->Location` only `Use wireless network` is checked, and I am not connected to the internet via Wi-Fi, I can not get a location fix.

I know there was something that the network provider uses availability of cell tower, but I don't know how that works exactly and should I have full internet access.

Please someone make this clear for me.

Comment: Are you using the "network" location provider in your code? (it might be named different)  Are you getting any exceptions anywhere?  Are you getting 0,0 fixes, bad fixes, or simply no fixes returned?

Comment: I am not getting fixes at all. If I am not connected to the internet there is no location fix. As soon as I connect, location is found. I am using the network provider, I also tried using providers with setting criteria: accuracy_fine and accuracy_coarse using this [link](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/using-two-locationproviders-on-android/). Also while browsing for some answers on the web I found sth that looks like similar to my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455802/android-if-both-gps-network-are-requested-at-the-same-time-network-provider-d). if you have some idea please share

Comment: I Experience this, even when I am connected, but have depleted my data plan. It seems that some providers need to send mobile data to the phone for the network provider location to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need to be connected to the Internet in order to get correct network location fixes. At least most of the time.

The phone collects the following data (it does **not** need a connection to the Internet to do this):

- nearby wifi information by scanning for wifi access points
- nearby mobile cell information is available from the phone's cellular radio

The phone then sends this data to a server. The server uses this data to look in its database to determine the phone's most likely position. The server sends the location information back to the phone. This is all done using data connection via Internet (either mobile Internet or wifi).

Some implementations additionally download a small amount of the server's database to the phone (describing a small area around the phone's current position) so that the phone doesn't have to query the Internet all the time. **However**, once the phone has moved outside of this small area it will need to access the Internet to get correct locations again.

So, basically, without Internet connectivity you can't (reliably) use network location.

Comment: Thank u for your response. You mention "some implementations additionally download a small amount of the server's database to the phone". What do I need to implement for that? Because in the case where there is no reliable location, it's better to provide any location (or an area as you say) than no location at all.

Comment: Sandra, you can't implement this yourself. When I said that "some implementations..." I meant that it is up to the implementer of the location provider. You have no control over this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: This looks to be a possible situation, I am experiencing similar results as said. If once a location is received with internet on, you will keep receiving them (even without internet) till you are in that particular cell block, once you move then without internet you wont get any new location update.

Comment: Great answer. One question on this: Do Android cache these small areas that it downloads and use it when we go back to the location again?

Comment: @AnilVK yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide more info on cache. Few questions: 1. How long does android keep this cache data? 2. Does it use accelerometer or compass on top of the cached data to provide location when device is offline. 3? Is there a way to delete this cache data?

Comment: @AnilVK no, sorry, I can't give you more details. This could be manufacturer-specific solution, and I imagine there are many factors that control it. However, as far as I understand, compass and accelerometer are NOT used in the location calculations. You can manually clear the location cache from Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > All (tab) > "Network Location", click on it to open and click on 'Clear data'.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect network location to work differently depending on the carrier.  It will need connection to the network, and really I wouldn't be surprised if that's classified as a data connection.

You can figure it out yourself through experimenting, but that's probably what prompted the question.

To get a definitive answer you'd probably have to talk to someone from the carrier. If they have a developer program that'd be your best bet.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but my question is just, do I need to be connected to internet to receive location fixes from the network provider. (gps is not active) How the network provider works? Can someone explain that to me in detail, if possible. Thank u