# Network-based geolocation in off-line smartphone

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

Very simple question: does network-based geolocation (either cell phone tower or wifi AP) work without an internet connection?

If not, could you somehow cache the cell phone and wifi ap database for specific areas? Could I download a full database of all wifi access points and cell phone towers in Belgium, and filter those near to my tourist locations?

*Background information:*
I want to make a smartphone app that alerts you when you are near a tourist location. I have a database with the addresses of all tourist locations (and can thus find lattitude/longitude).
I do not want to rely on GPS as it drains the battery too much. The phone will not have a data connection.

Comment: Hmm, I found http://www.openwlanmap.org/ and http://www.openbmap.org/ as open WLan and tower databases

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270154/cannot-get-current-location-until-connected-to-the-internet-android-gps

Comment: The 3GPP2 specification provides for the longitude and lattitude within the Cell broadcast message. See http://www.3gpp2.org/public_html/specs/C.S0005-A_v6.0.pdf and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html for more information. However, it seems that this standard is only implemented in Japan, not in US or EU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the phone need to be connected to the internet so that the network provider can determine a location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997169/does-the-phone-need-to-be-connected-to-the-internet-so-that-the-network-provider)